# Run a script only after another one completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have multiple scripts in my HTML header. the two of concern are as follows:

1) JS script ('Infected Data') produces an object with data. The data is retrieved and computed from a google scripts file, so naturally it takes a bit.

2) A script which generates a map. The map is color coded depending on the values of the Infected Object Data.

The problem is the map loads before i can get the object, so it is not colored.

Map should look like this:
[image]
Map looks like this:
[image]

**HTML Header:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>JQVMap - World Map</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

        <link href="../dist/jqvmap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.deaths.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.infected.js"></script>


        <script>





          jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
              map: 'world_en',
              backgroundColor: '#333333',
              color: '#ffffff',
              hoverOpacity: 0.8,
              selectedColor: '#3498DB',
              enableZoom: true,
              showTooltip: true,
              scaleColors: ['#F3A291', '#FF4F3B'],
              values: infected_data,
              normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
              onLabelShow: function(event, label, code)
        {
          // Remove for Russian Joke
            /*if (code == 'ru')
            {
                // Plain TEXT labels
                label.text('Bears, vodka, balalaika');
            }

            else*/


                label.html('<div class="map-tooltip"><h1 class="header">'+label.html()+'</h1><p class="description">Infected: '+infected_data[code]+'</p><p class="description">Deaths: '+death_data[code]+'</p></div>');


            /*else if (code == 'us')
            {

                label.html(label.html()+' (GDP - '+sample_data[code]+')');
            }*/
        },
        /*onRegionOver: function(event, code)
        {
            if (code == 'ca')
            {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        },            */
            });
          });
        </script>







</head>
```

**Infected Data JS FIle:**

```
    var infected_dataINT = {};
var infected_data = {};
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsyQNJwDvQc5SvNGEDZZOoNI3XxNar9PA9sRucZx7mgzfWpFQ/exec";

  // Declare an async function
  const getData = async () => {
  // Use the await keyword to let JS know this variable has some latency so it should wait for it to be filled 
  // When the variable is fetched, use the .then() callback to carry on 
    const DataJSON = await fetch(url).then(response => 
      response.json()
    )

    return await DataJSON
  };



  console.log(getData());

  getData().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    infected_dataINT = result;
    console.log(infected_dataINT);

    function toString(o) {
      Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
          return toString(o[k]);
        }

        o[k] = '' + o[k];
      });

      return o;
    }

    console.log(toString(infected_dataINT));
    infected_data = toString(infected_dataINT);

  })
```

How can i slow down the `jQuery(document).ready(function () {....` to run only after `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.infected.js"></script>` has ran

Comment: Please use the correct document structure and ensure everything begins with the ONLOAD event so that 3rd party libraries may all load and synchronize... <html> <head> <style type="text/css"> </style> </head> <body onload="Function_That_KickStarts_Everything();"> <script src="Third_Party_Library_1.js"></script> <script src="Third_Party_Library_2.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> </script> </body> </html>

Comment: You should look into the library if they support any "onComplete" events, if it does, add an eventListener and load the second library then.

Comment: The order in which you call the script doesn't help you much. One script may load faster than others depending on many things like net speed, server from where you are getting the response and size of the js file and other things. As Map depends on data you should not render the map to real DOM, wait till you have data in hand.

Comment: Yep! Exactly what I’m thinking. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically append the script element to the document after the response has been recieved from the server like this:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'myJqueryFile.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

You just have to put those jquery codes inside a .js file.

Comment: @CamdenS you remove the script tag containing the jQuery codes. Because your infect.js file is async and it's request will probably resolve after the next scipt tag is executed. So after the response is reached from the server you create an script element and set its src attr equal to the name of a file that contains your jquery codes. `document.head.appendchild(script)` will place the newly created script element to the DOM dynamically. I suggest you read a little bit about DOM manipulation and dynamically loaded scripts if you wanna get a deeper knowledge on this topic.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks I’ll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an asynch problem...

Where do you close the header?

```
</head>
```

And where is your onload event to synchrinise things?

```
<body onload="Function_That_KickStarts_Everything();">
```

Comment: The head closes, look at the html file. I’m not sure I have an onload function

Answer (score 0):

Please use the correct document structure and ensure everything begins with the ONLOAD event so that 3rd party libraries may all load and synchronize... follow this please:

```
<html>

<head>

 <style type="text/css">

 </style>

</head>

<body onload="Function_That_KickStarts_Everything();">

 <script src="Third_Party_Library_1.js"></script>

 <script src="Third_Party_Library_2.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">

 </script>


</body>

</html>
```